# At what values of $\beta$ for which $\sum a_n$ converges, where $a_n=\sqrt{1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^\beta}}-1\,$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, analysis, convergence-divergence

I posted this kind of question before, but didn't get an appropriate answer. However, this is what I'm trying to do. I want to find the values of $\beta$ for which $\sum a_n$ converges, where $a_n=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^\beta}}-1\,$. Here is what I have done after the hints below, were provided:

$$a_n=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^\beta}}-1\,=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2\,n^\beta}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{2\beta}}\right)$$

$$\sum a_n=\sum \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2\,n^\beta}$$

It seems as if my former Taylor estimate was wrong. So, can anyone help me from here?

Comment: I've updated the title with the $a_n$ indicated also in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $\beta \le 0$ it suffices to observe that the series is not well defined or

- $|a_n|\not \to 0$

Thus, for $\beta > 0$ by binomial expansion we have that

$$a_n=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^\beta}}-1= \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n^\beta} -\dfrac{1}{8n^{2\beta}}+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{16n^{3\beta}}-\dfrac{5}{128n^{4\beta}}+\dots$$

and since

- for the alternating term, by [**alternating series test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), for convergence we need $\beta >0$
- for not alternating terms we need $2\beta>1,\,4\beta>1,\,\dots2k\beta>1\implies \beta>\frac 1 {2k}\, \forall k\in \mathbb{N}$

then the given series converges for $\beta>0$.

Comment: Please, check my edit! Am I right?

Comment: The title makes confusion since it us different from the OP. I will update asap for the question presented in the OP.

Comment: Sorry to ask! Why negative before the first term?

Comment: ops...just a typo, I fix

Comment: Aright, got it!

Answer (score 3):

If $ \beta \le 0$, the sequence $(a_n)$ does not converge to $0$, hence the series is divergent.

If $ \beta >0$, then, by Leibniz, the series is convergent.

Comment: By Liebniz? Please, I don't know about that!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: The alternating series test definitely doesn't apply when $\beta < 1$ because the absolute value of the sequence is not monotonically decreasing!

Comment: @ Michael Lee: That's true! Even by p-series test!

Comment: @MichaelLee $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ is not decreasing ?

Comment: Are you taking $\beta = 1/2$ there? You may want to try plugging in a few values of $n$, because $\lvert a_n\rvert\neq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. For $\beta = 1/2$, $a_1 = -1$, $a_2 = 0.3065...$, $a_3 = -0.349885...$, $a_4 = 0.2247...$, $a_5 = -0.2565...$

Comment: If you try to, say, rearrange the series so that you swap $a_3$ with $a_2$, $a_5$ with $a_4$, etc., you will find that this is invalid, generally speaking, because the series is not absolutely convergent when $\beta < 1$.

Comment: @Mike You cannot use the $p$-series test to discount the possibility of convergence here because of the alternating signs, but the alternating sign test as is does not directly give convergence. You will need to use your Taylor error estimate.

Comment: @ Michael Lee: Got that!

Comment: @MichaelLee What are you talking about ?? $1, 0.7, 0.58, 0.5,\ldots$ Everyone knows that $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ decreases to $0$...

Comment: @GabrielRomon You are missing the fact that $a_n$ is not actually $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$, even when $\beta = 1/2$. The first-order Taylor estimate is obviously not exact, so a little more work must be done to show convergence of the series.

Comment: Damn, I looked only at the title of the question, that's why...

Comment: True, the title is misleading.

Comment: Alright then! Could someone just help me edit the question?

Comment: Also, @Mike you may want to double-check your Taylor estimate.

Comment: @ Michael Lee: Sorry for that!

Comment: @ Michael Lee: Thanks also for the edit. Could I still apply the definition of absolute convergence?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n^{\beta}} = \left(\frac{1}{2^{\beta}}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\zeta(\beta)$$ which is finite iff $\beta > 0$. Let's take $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n^{\beta}} < \frac{1}{2}$ for $n\geq N$. Then, the first-order Taylor error estimate gives us $$R_1(x) = \max_{\lvert z\rvert < 1/2} \frac{x^2}{8(1+z)^{3/2}}\leq \frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{2}}$$ for all $\lvert x\rvert\leq 1/2$, so we choose $M\in \mathbb{N}$, $M\geq N$, such that $\sup_{k,l\geq M} \left\lvert\sum_{n=k}^l \frac{(-1)^n}{2n^{\beta}}\right\rvert\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\sup_{k,l\geq M} \sum_{n=k}^l \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}n^{2\beta}}\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (again, only works iff $\beta > 1/2$). Then, $$\sup_{k,l\geq M} \left\lvert\sum_{n=k}^l a_n\right\rvert\leq \epsilon$$ by the Taylor error estimate, so the sequence of partial sums is Cauchy (i.e. convergent). We can use higher-order estimates to disprove convergence for $\beta\leq 1/2$:

Take the estimate $\sqrt{1+x}-1 = \frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+O(x^3)$, for example. Let $x = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\beta}}$. For $\beta\leq 1/2$, we have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{(-1)^n}{2n^{\beta}}-\frac{1}{8n^{2\beta}}\right]$ diverges, but for $n > 2^{1/\beta}$ the error in any given term is bounded above by $$R_2(x) = \max_{\lvert z\rvert < 1/2} \frac{\lvert x\rvert^3}{16(1+z)^{5/2}} = \frac{\lvert x\rvert^3}{18\sqrt{6}} = \frac{1}{18\sqrt{6}n^{3\beta}}$$ which is summable for $\beta > 1/3$, implying that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ must diverge for $1/3 < \beta\leq 1/2$. We can extend this argument for all $\beta > 0$ by taking higher-order Taylor expansions.

Comment: This is superb!

Comment: Thanks! I've just fixed the argument for $\beta\leq 1/2$.